# How to Configure IntelliJ debug to auto reload changes with Jersey in a Grizzly container

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jersey, grizzly

I have created a Jersey startup project using this Maven archetype which available from this [page](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/getting-started.html)

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=jersey-quickstart-grizzly2 
-DarchetypeGroupId=org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes -DinteractiveMode=false 
-DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=simple-service -Dpackage=com.example 
-DarchetypeVersion=2.25.1
```

This will create a sample project that will run using Grizzly container, i.e. you produce a jar then run the main method which will start the Grizzly container and host the application.

I have managed to add a debug configuration in IntelliJ using the Maven profile but I don't know how to configure it to auto reload changes and restart the application or better without restarting the application if possible (hot reload)